# JavaScript: .push() replaces all the stored values with the values of last object pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

i'm quite new to JavaScript.. i'm basically writing this different shapes drawing (on canvas) program in which when user can draw shapes on canvas after clicking the desired shape button... code of that looks like this:

```
var rectangle = document.getElementById('rec');
rectangle.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    x2 =  y2 = 0;
    globalOption = 'rec';
    var rec = new shape();
    e.preventDefault();
}, false)
```

after that in the init function.. on mousedown event:

```
else if(globalOption == 'rec')
    {           
        e.target.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
        rec.name = 'rec';
        started = 'true';
        x2 = y2 = 0;
        x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        rec.x = x;
        rec.y = y;
        //context.beginPath();
    }
```

i'm storing all the information about this shape in the shape object i created earlier in addEventListener code "var rec = new shape();". I'm pushing this object in an array on mouse up event. Now the problem is that, it stores only the information of last pushed object.. even though array length is correct.. but all the objects it contains have one same information of the last object pushed! Why's that?? i tried placing "var rec = new shape();" line on different places but no use!

Comment: can you show the code for when you push?  I'm just guessing here, but it sounds like you're pushing a reference rather than a copy, so when you change the one object it will change every index in the array.  do you call new shape() with every click or just once?

Comment: new shape is in the click event of the button, so yea i call it every time.. and here is the push code:
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
  if(globalOption == 'pen')
   {
    started = false;
   }
   if(globalOption == 'eraser')
   {
    started = false;
   }
   else if(globalOption == 'rec')
   {
    started = false;
    context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
    tempCanvas.width = tempCanvas.width;
    shapes.push(rec);
   }

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing all of your code together, but I don't see how `rec` is defined in that code. You define it in your `click` handler, but I'm assuming that is out of scope for your `mouseup` handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a new object and copy the data from rec to it. And then push the new object to the array. Otherwise it will only keep the reference to the 'rec' variable and that's why you always get the last element.

Comment: I just tried this instead of simple shapes.push(rec):
var newRec = new shape();
newRec = rec;
shapes.push(newrec);

Still same result..

Comment: you are still just passing the reference only. try copying the properties of the object one by one to the new object

Comment: omg it worked! i created a newRec shape() and copied each element one by one then pushed the newRec.. and now each pushed object has its own values!!
var newRec = new shape();
    newRec.fill = rec.fill;
    newRec.font = rec.font;
    newRec.h = rec.h;
    newRec.name = rec.name;
    newRec.prototype = rec.prototype;
    newRec.r = rec.r;
    newRec.size = rec.size;
    newRec.text = rec.text;
    newRec.w = rec.w;
    newRec.x = rec.x;
    newRec.y = rec.y;
    shapes.push(newRec);

Comment: I solved it doing let new_obj = {...old_obj}; myArray.push(old_obj). Weird issue, but I've seen it before with react. This does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was copying each object by reference.. what it required was creating a new object, copying each value one by one and then pushing that new object!